# Open-Collector to Push-Pull

Tags: pullup, push-pull, open-collector

In a project I am using a 74LS05 to provide an ESP32 microcontroller with 6 open-collector outputs. Actually this is fine for 5 of the outputs, but for the remaining one I'd rather have a full push-pull driver, since the rise time I currently have is still too high (and I am already using a 470 ohm pull-up resistor).

I cannot use an ESP32 output directly since the output needs to be at +5V when high.

I'd like to keep the solution as simple as possible. I was thinking that maybe I could add an external BJT or MOSFET to "complement" the open-collector output but I have no idea of how to do that.

Any hints?

EDIT: Here's some additional info:

- I don't want to add a 74xx04 for just one output, the other 5 outputs are fine open-collector-style.
- I am using LS logic because the project is retrocomputing-related. I could switch to an HCT but would that change much?
- I don't know the exact characteristics of the input I have to drive. it's the right mouse button input of the Amiga Paula custom chip, which is notoriously hard to drive.
- I can take some measurements with a scope if that helps.
- On a different project I am driving the same input straight from an output pin of an AVR microcontroller and in that case the signal rises "immediately".

EDIT2: Here's an old scope screenshot showing how slow the signal is rising (blue). It needs to be high before the following clock rising edge (yellow). I can't remember what pull-up value I was using when I took this screenshot though, maybe 1k or 820 ohm.

[image]

Comment: The ESP32 can't drive the 74LS05 directly.It might be simpler just to use 5 mosfets & resistors for the OC outputs and something like a 74HCT04 for the push-pull output.

Comment: You must define C load @ 470 =R and max rise time. No good reason to use LS TTL.

Comment: @Kartman What is the reason you say that ESP32 cannot drive a 74LS05 directly - I think it can, very well.

Comment: Use a 74LS04? Why would you want anything other than the obvious solution? In other words, you need to be a lot more clear about your requirements and constraints.

Comment: How much 5V push pull current drive ability and specific voltage levels you need at those current levels? What is the target you are driving with 5V push-pull signal?

Comment: @Kartman: A 74LS05 has a much more well-defined \$V_{IH(min)}\$ than a bare MOSFET does.

Comment: I have edited the question to reply to some questions, please see above.

Comment: It sounds like you're much more concerned about risetime than delay. Just put a fast comparator on that sixth output. You can also get a single-gate Schmitt trigger.

Comment: ESP32 doesn’t sound very retro ;) how about an MC6800?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The output of the system is for a retro device, the input is not :). Project page is here: https://gitlab.com/SukkoPera/unijoysticle2

Comment: @SukkoPera The Paula POT input POTY for the R mouse button is meant for reading potentiometers. You are not supposed to drive it high with a push-pull stage to begin with, no Amiga mouse does that.

Comment: @Justme I don't see how feeding 5V into it could be a problem, in fact the CD32 controller does exactly that (http://gerdkautzmann.de/cd32gamepad/cd32gamepad.html) and that's what I'm trying to replicate. I'm all good except that the signal rises slooooowly and sometimes the reading is not correct. EDIT: Added a scope shot to the question.

Comment: @SukkoPera If you are replicating it, then why not replicate it with the 74LS125, or with some other LS TTL chip?

Comment: @Justme: Because the current design is 99% working, I'd really like to avoid adding 2 new ICs and basically disrupt the whole design. I have a feeling a properly-connected simple transistor would do the job, but I am very incompetent in analog stuff.

Comment: @SukkoPera Why 2 new ICs? You could remove the 74LS05, and have a design with two identical 74LS125 chips, use it for both open-collector and push-pull lines. Besides any standard TTL input would work with 3.3V levels, but I understand that we have no datasheet for Paula voltage levels.

Comment: @Justme: that might be a way, but it still looks like a totale redesign to me. The project is like it is now because it's a rather simple modification of another one and I'd like it to stay to way. If I cannot improve the situation, well, I'll get away with it.

Comment: Feel free to post new results with 270 to 330 R pullup.

Comment: Sure. I won't be able to work on it for a couple of days though.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I didn't have a 270 R so I tried with 220: did not work, looked like the line couldn't be pulled down. So I switched to 330 and things started to look better. Then I realized I could put 1k5 in parallel to get 270 and so I did. Now the signal gets to around 4V before the next clock edge, which seems to work fine and leave a decent margin. Here's a pic: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvuk4us3aqka1z8/unijoysticle_nolowlib_270vs330r.png?dl=0, grey line is with 330, blue is 270. So thanks a lot for helping find the smallest pull-up value I could use.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a slow rising input signal to a fast rising output signal using the following circuit (in blue dotted box):[image]

Here are the input (green) and output (blue) waveforms:[image]

The circuit on the left is to simulate the slow rising input voltage. The capacitor on the right is just to show that it is able to drive the output high fast enough even with 50pF capacitive load.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a [MC74VHC1GT50](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc74vhc1g50-d.pdf) to an open-collector with pullup resistor output, will give a TTL level output which can source/sink 8mA. It is one 6 pin surface mount chip.

Comment: Thanks, this might be a way but I feel a bit dirty adding a SMT component to a 100% THT board. That's why I was looking for a way to do it with a discrete transitor.

Answer (score 0):

The analog characteristics of logic are computed by the. Vol/Iol and Vil/Iil output and input low impedance ratios. All TTL families differed in speed and power yet maintained a 10:1 fan-out ratio. This applies to both current and resistance.

The 74LS05 is an inverting Open Collector with an output saturation resistance of 25 Ohms maximum ( 400 mVmax/16mA) and an input Vil Resistance if 250 Ohms minimum (400mV/1.6mAmax).  the input voltage threshold for all TLL is two Vbe drops or 1.3 but for noise power immunity, the thresholds were defined safely as “0” = <= 0.8V and “1” = >2.0V.

Similarly impedance for 3.3V logic has been designed for 22 Ohm drivers @ 3.0V and this lowers slightly at 3.6V.

Thus you can get superior performance driving LS logic directly from 3.3 V CMOS logic such as the ESP32 family.  If for any reason your wires are too inductive, and ringing causes logic errors, this can be well-damped pulses with same risetime by adding 50 to 150 series from 3.3V logic to drive  say a 240 Ohm ribbon cable or twisted pairs.

For open collector outputs or switch contacts from the joystick, you just need any suitable pullup R’s.

### Thus there is no need to add redundant interface circuitry to drive a TTL Joystick from 3.3 Logic.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I appreciate it. Unfortunately, I probably didn't explain myself well enough, as this does not answer what I was asking. I can drive the direction and button 1 pins well enough, I have problems driving pin 9 when emulating a CD32 controller. This pin ends into an ADC built in Paula and has weird driving characteristics that make signals rise very slowly . Please see the question again, I have added a few details.

Comment: Not enough details . Can you use this to define which  on here https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoqMp.png. there are shunt caps to intentionally slow down rise time. If you don’t explain the specs, how can anyone understand if what you expect is correct.  Anyways the ESP32 has 22 ohm drivers so the rise time and fall time will be just as fast if that’s what you need.

Comment: Ignore the -1 lame. Vote

Comment: It's the POT0Y or POT1Y signals. The ESP32 cannot bear with the pull-ups to +5V that are inside the Amiga (Resistor Network R370), that's why we resorted to using a 7405. Please have a look at my project (and scope trace above) and suggest the *simplest* way to get a quicker rising signal, that's the only problem I have left.

Comment: POT0Y or POT1Y on pins 9,5 do not connect to R370 pull-ups on Pins 1 to 4 . Which one is it again? To drive 5V with 4k7 pullup to 2V =logic “1” you pull down to gnd with 3.3k to get 2V then the 22 Ohm 0 to 3.3 V driver pulls down below 0.8V and  above 2V to 3V from 3.3 to be compatible.

Comment: That's why I said that 5 of the 6 outputs of the 7405 are fine: those go to pins 1/2/3/4/6 of the joystick port and everything is fine. The 6th output goes to pin 9 and is fine when in "Atari" joystick mode, but it's not when in CD32 mode. You can see from the scope pic above that the signal barely rises to a high logic level in time for the following clock pulse. Everything will be clearer if you take a look at the schematics of my project.

Comment: Something else I should mention is that when in Atari mode, a pull-up to 5V internal to Paula gets enabled. It seems to get disabled in CD32 mode so I provide my own. Anyway this means I can't use an ESP32 output directly.

Comment: We are talking about 5V TTL logic which only needs to be 0.8 to 2V  so if a pullup exists to 5V, it is unnecessary for 3.3V driver which will work as I said with 3k3 pulldown. you still didn't answer my question on interface specs which you don't seem to understand

Comment: Paula is a similarly contrived contraction of Ports, Audio, UART and Logic, and coincidentally the chip designer's girlfriend.  The POT0Y and 1Y signals are  from an analog pot with cap filter ,so you shouldn't be driving it with a pulse. It's Analog.

Comment: I am trying to explain the specs the best I can but I agree we don't seem to understand each other. I'll try to be as straight as I can: forget the ESP32 and Paula, just think about how you can speed up the rising time of a 7405 output.

Comment: The LS05 specs as I said are 16mA  @ 400mV max, so it can pull down a 280 Ohm pull up resistor to 5V, try 330 to 270 Ohms. as long as low level is < 0.8V you got logic "0" satisfied even though the threshold is 1.3V. So simply add a 270 Pullup

Comment: The 74LS05 datasheets I found from various manufacturers only went up to 8mA @ 0.4V, not 16mA. The 74LS125 did have a stronger sinking ability.

Comment: @Justme Those are the abbreviated datasheet values over temp range. The ones with schematics show 16mA at 25’C https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7405.pdf. And BJTs run better with self heating in TTL opposite to CMOS

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Oh I see now - the non-LS regular 7405 is different, it does have 16mA rating, but the 74LS05 which the OP uses has 8mA rating according to the same datasheet.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my memory from 1980 and 74S is 20mA .  The solution will still work much better with lower pullup of 270 R with + 75mW and much less in driver.

Comment: Someone here (-1) does not understand that logic gates are also analog.